# How do I change js3-mode's indentation style?

Tags: javascript, emacs, indentation, auto-indent

I am using Emacs and `js3-mode` to edit some javascript code. After I write the following code and indent it, I see this:

```
var returnValue = someFunction(function () {
                     console.log('This is a callback');
                  });
```

What I want is this:

```
var returnValue = someFunction(function () {
  console.log('This is a callback');
});
```

It looks like `js3-mode` is trying to align the callback with the call to `someFunction`, but I don't want that. How do I change the indentation style?

Side note: That code was just an example, it's not actually the code I'm editing, but the situation is similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [js3-mode wiki](https://github.com/thomblake/js3-mode/wiki/AlternateStyles), add this to you init file

```
(setq js3-consistent-level-indent-inner-bracket t)
```

Comment: You might also like `(setq js3-boring indentation t)` which makes a lot of the indentation much simpler.